# Selenium webdriver: can I check if a resource (e.g. XML file) has been loaded?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have Fusion Maps and Fusion Charts in my application, which load XML files to get data to visualise.

What I would like to do is, using JUnit tests (webdriver), to check if a certain XML file has been loaded (or, at an higher level, that a file has been loaded).

Is this even possible?

I know that I can do by making javascript calls but I am doubtful about doing js calls from java code...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing JS calls from java. You can read how to do them [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?).

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way (even with the html unit driver) to find if an asset has been downloaded (be it an image, or xml file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just wondering if making lots of JS calla might affect either the performance or the stability of the tests